# django rest API route showing same api link for all end point

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created a small Task app & define some end point like all task, Due Task, Completed Task.

Here is my url.py

```
#Define API Routes
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
#router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'task', views.TaskViewSet)
router.register(r'due_task', views.DueTaskViewSet)
router.register(r'completed_task', views.CompletedTaskViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'TaskAPI.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^',include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Serializers.py

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =  Task
        fields = ('id','task_name','task_desc','completed','date_created')
```

View.py

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Task.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

class DueTaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all().order_by('-date_created').filter(completed=False)
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

class CompletedTaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all().order_by('-date_created').filter(completed=True)
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

model.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    task_desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

when I run server & hit 127.0.0.1:8080 API route windows will open with all endpoint pointing to the same link.

[image]

please suggest what is going wrong here.
Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to see your serializer code. I'm going to assume your `task`, `due_task` and `completed_task` are relations. If that's the case DRF uses a `HyperlinkedRelatedField` by default.

Comment: @themanatuf: i have updated my code. please look into it. thanks

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not 100% sure how DRF works behind the scenes, but my guess is since you defined three views with the same serializer, DRF is using the last one. Maybe try filtering one viewset rather than having three: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: @themanatuf: Thanks, but is it not possible in DRF to use the same Serializer with different view.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed confusing DRF.  Perhaps it should be able to handle your case, but it cannot.

I would collapse all three `viewsets` into one `viewset` with optional filters:

```
from rest_framework import filters

class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    filter_fields = ('completed',)
    ordering = ('-date_created',)

    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter,)
```

Then, query conditionally with the `completed` parameter:

```
/completed_task/
/completed_task/?completed=True
/completed_task/?completed=False
```

Comment: - Thanks for the solution, I agree with you.  but is it possible to use the same serializer to different viewset.
if i want to create different end points without query parameter then how to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  I once tried to do that.  I set a breakpoint and started going down the rabbit hole.  Anyways, I gave up, so I'm not sure how one does that.  You'll probably want to step into the `router.register` code base to figure out how to get DRF to do _exactly_ what you're asking.  In the mean time:  Filters! :-)

Comment: It seems to boil down to router implementation in DRF. Currently, both simple and default routers use lowercase model name as the unique identifier for registered routes `queryset.model._meta.object_name.lower()`. If you really want to avoid filters and do it the way you intended, you might want to subclass default router and override get_default_base_name(). Look at the SimpleRouter and BaseRouter implementation code for details, it is fairly easy to read.

Answer (score 25):

You probably need to specify the optional `base_name` argument in the `register()` method. It's normally auto-generated. However, the same serializer and relatively similar querysets might be why you're getting the same endpoint. I think you want something like this.

```
router.register(r'task', views.TaskViewSet, 'task')
router.register(r'due_task', views.DueTaskViewSet, 'due_task')
router.register(r'completed_task', views.CompletedTaskViewSet, 'completed_task')
```

According to the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage):

> If unset the basename will be automatically generated based on the `queryset` attribute of the viewset, if it has one. Note that if the viewset does not include a `queryset` attribute then you must set `base_name` when registering the viewset.